# Open ag-grid-enterprise side bar on button click

Tags: css, angular, ag-grid-angular

I am currently working on ag-grid-enterprise 17.1.0 version. My requirement is to display grid's side bar on a button click, kind of toggle. Also, the "Columns" and "Filters" bar orientation should be changed.
Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Could someone please help here.

Answer (score 1):

The docs show an example for exactly this usecase:

```
sideBar = {
    toolPanels: [
        {
            id: 'columns',
            labelDefault: 'Columns',
            labelKey: 'columns',
            iconKey: 'columns',
            toolPanel: 'agColumnsToolPanel',
        },
        {
            id: 'filters',
            labelDefault: 'Filters',
            labelKey: 'filters',
            iconKey: 'filter',
            toolPanel: 'agFiltersToolPanel',
        }
    ],
    position: 'left',       // <---- set position
    defaultToolPanel: 'filters'
}

<ag-grid-angular
      #agGrid
      style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
      id="myGrid"
      class="ag-theme-balham"
      [modules]="modules"
      [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
      [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
      [sideBar]="sideBar"           // <----
      [rowData]="rowData"
      (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
    ></ag-grid-angular>
```

also you can open / close the Sidebar like this:

```
gridApi.closeToolPanel();
gridApi.openToolPanel("columns");
```

See here: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-side-bar/#side-bar-api

(yes, i know, these docs are for the current Version of ag-grid - but the api should also be similar to the one they used in v17)